# MATLAB: Create a predefined array of images

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I need to load many small grayscale images in MATLAB. All images are of the same type/size.
How can I predefine an array and place a different image in each of its cell?

For example, an array of 100 images, inserting an image at position 50:

```
my_array = zeros(100);
...
my_array(50) = my_image;
...
imshow(my_array(50));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a cell array, simply define it as:

```
my_array = cell(100,1);

my_array{50} = my_image;

imshow(my_array{50})
```

Each cell of a cell array can hold different size arrays and types. I did assume that your `my_image` variable was an array. Also notice the curly brackets, this is how you access/define the content in a cell array. Here is a small example:

```
a = rand(100); % 100x100 size array in cell position 1
r = rand(100,100,3); % Different size array in cell position 2
b = cell(2,1); % initialize cell
b{1} = a; % assign cell content
b{2} = r;
imshow(b{1})
```

[image: imshow(b{1})]

The image is the results of `imshow(b{1})`